# Can I develop a Newsstand app without downloading content?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, newsstand-kit

I want to try building a Newsstand app, but want to concentrate on a viewer component first.  Can I "preload" a sample issue into the iPhone Simulator or onto my device?  For the sake of developing this component, I want to assume that the content has already been downloaded into the Newsstand repository.